# How do I get the correct $PATHs for remote Python Fabric Access?

Tags: python, bash, ssh, path, fabric

I am writing a python program that establishes a ssh connection to a server.
For this I am using fabric (fabfile.org).

When I connect to the server via ssh in a terminal, I get my $PATHs set.
When I connect to the server via fabric in my python program, $PATHs are missing...

1. Where does bash load the $PATHs when I connect via terminal?
2. How do I manage that fabric does the same?

Thanks in advance!

edit:
this is what I get, when I run `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}`:

SSH via Terminal:

```
/home/myusername/bin
/home/myusername/.local/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/mpich-3.4.2-npjoxvgsi2nthnyp5shm42is7wzxdll7/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/libfabric-1.12.1-mzleboxdvvcdtdwg7qg6wf54xwvsmyoz/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/rdma-core-34.0-rf4h4kiatax6su3acacuxu33vxpq5mh4/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/libnl-3.3.0-ih7pa4rn4nuvraaomc4c2ou6f2opyyve/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/hwloc-2.4.1-djw5rieilo4sypmpsew5rudmesqaw7mp/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/ncurses-6.2-fsd347mkpmp6iezvqzfrn4mqj4wi42be/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/libxml2-2.9.10-rjlorqqgjthe6pheei3mbug73tqdjy74/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/xz-5.2.5-oxdrliw6ak4a54igymkcim5l7w2gcmx2/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-11.1.0/libiconv-1.16-dqvkzxma2htfkms66pdqtntndl7gqpzf/bin
/opt/spack/20210902/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/gcc-7.5.0/gcc-11.1.0-5ikoznknx7aaqakigpo7nriui22lrle5/bin
/opt/vampir/9.3.0/bin
/opt/matlab/R2016a/bin
/opt/ddt/5.0.1/bin
/opt/spack/current/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

SSH via Fabric:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
I got to run `source /etc/profile` with fabric in order to get my correct PATHs.

Found out by reading:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: when I `c.run("source /etc/profile"); c.run("echo $PATH")`, then the sourcing doesn't have any effect. did they hcange anything lately?